# Simplifying Assembly Instruction

Tags: c, assembly, att

I'm trying to convert the following code into a single line using leal.

```
movl 4(%esp), %eax
sall $2, %eax
addl 8(%esp), %eax
addl $4, %eax
```

My question is of 3 parts:

1. Does the '%' in front of the register simply define the following string as a register?
2. Does the '$' in front of the integers define the following value type as int?
3. Is `leal 4(%rsi, 4, %rdi), %eax` a correct conversion from the above assembly? (ignoring the change from 32-bit to 64-bit)

Edit: Another question. would

```
unsigned int fun3(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    unsigned int *z = &x;
    unsigned int w = 4+y;        
    return (4*(*z)+w);             
}
```

generate the above code? I'm unfamiliar with pointers.

Comment: There aren't any ampersands in your post. Not sure what character you mean.

Comment: I think he means '%' when he writes "ampersand".

Comment: [Starting point](http://wiki.osdev.org/Opcode_syntax) on AT&T assembly syntax. Check the "Sources" links at the bottom.

Comment: lea loads an address instead of loading from memory. The example assembly code loads from memory twice, so you need two instructions just to get the data into registers. Once the data is in registers, you can scale one of them by 4 to get the equivalent of the shift left (ignoring sign bit issues), and use an offset of 4 with lea.

Comment: A followup question: between the two types of assembly code, is there one that is considered more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: if % yes

2: there is no int or float or bool or char or... in asm. You are dealing with the machine.  It means it is a constant

3: 1 move value in (esp - 4) to eax. esp is the stack pointer, eax is the register used by c function to return values.

2 shift to left two times.  same as multiply by 4

3 add value in (esp - 8) to value in eax

4 add 4 to value in eax

x*4+y+4 = eax  x is (esp -4), y is (esp-8)

leal is the same as, 4+rsi+4*rdi =eax

so yes it the same in a way.

That depend on the compiler, but yes that is valid translation. 4*x+y+4